# Achartengine discontinuous line

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to make some dataseries with a discontinuous line? I want to show two different datasets but they must have the same color so it would really help to do something to make the difference. Changing the points for triangles or something else does not work because the dataset is made up of too many values so the graph becames very messy¨

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
renderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.DASHED);
```

or

```
renderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.DOTTED);
```

You could change the thickness of the line to differentiate them

```
renderer.setLineWidth(2);
```

Or fill in under the line

```
renderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
```